# Joomla 2.5.9 User Registration

Tags: joomla2.5, registration

I am using Joomla 2.5.9 and using a standard registration page although I get every validation error when trying to register someone.

It's telling me that my name is not valid, my username is not valid and my passwords do not match when I have triple checked that they do.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Have you customized anything? This normally works (as I'm sure you guessed) so we would need to know more about what you have done that may lead to this.

Comment: I assume you have edited some of the Joomla core code, which should not be done. Try downloading a fresh copy of Joomla and upload it.

Comment: Do what @Lodder said. if it doesn't work, check if you have template overrides? check your template's folder /templates/your_template/html/com_users/registration. If the folder is there, rename it and try again. If it's not there, you don't have template overrides for com_users